# Footer placing, not in the bottom of window, but in the bottom of the content

Tags: html, css, footer

i once got this template, and it got its footer's css like this

```
footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: -3em;
left: 0;
right: 0;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}
```

I'm using a php for dynamic content
but, every time my content (wrapped in div, right before the footer) changes,
as it change it's lenght (height), this footer suddenly change its position and suddenly placed near the top (highest div on web page) div.

i was wondering how to make this footer stay in the bottom of the page,
i was seeking one, but i just found {postition:fixed;}, i was meant to place my footer "as the last content, in the bottom" not "stay in the bottom of screen/window"..

can anyone help?
thanks in advance

Comment: post your html code as well

Comment: You may be missing a </div> somewhere on the page.

Comment: my footer doesnt inherit things (except from body, wich is just font size) and those code i write here are the only css that affect footer,

Answer (score 0):

If your CODE is like bleow, then you are good to go

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative; background:grey;
    height:200px    
}
.footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: -3em;
left: 0;
right: 0;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xbc4k/)**

Change the `wrapper` height to see the difference

Comment: thanks. i think im forced to using div instead of html5's <footer> but thanks anyone who tried to help. i appreciates your helps.

Comment: @user2037589 even <footer> should work perfectly with this method. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/xbc4k/2/

Comment: im sorry i was too late to say that im using CI with Grocery crud library. i think a datatable is parsed later than the footer so the footer will placed in the middle of my datatable. can you give me advice to pake the footer appear, after the datatable is done generated.